# How to split a string into words and spaces?

Tags: python, string, split

I'd like to split a `string = ['O little forests,']` so that the output includes both words and spaces, with the last comma appended to the last words. Here's what the desired output should look like:

`output = ['O', ' ', 'little', ' ', 'forests,']`

I was able to split the given string into a list of words with spaces excluded by using `line.split()`. I welcome your suggestions!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include what you have tried. Does it work?

Comment: [Preserve whitespaces when using split() and join() in python](//stackoverflow.com/a/15579296)

Comment: Please share a [MCVE] of your attempts so we can know what has been tried and failed.  It also ensures we don't duplicate the effort in vian.

Comment: A small revision:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do this work using [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) like following code.

```
import re
string = ['O little forests'] 
for a  in string:
  print(re.split(r'(\s+)', a))
```

Output:

```
['O', ' ', 'little', ' ', 'forests']
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

sentence = 'O little forests'

result = [''.join(v) for k, v in groupby(sentence, key=str.isspace)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['O', ' ', 'little', ' ', 'forests']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use re (regex):

```
import re

sentence = 'O little forests'

re.split("( )", sentence) # ['O', ' ', 'little', ' ', 'forests']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a space element between each word like this in a list comprehension:

```
s = 'O little forest'
# puts ' ' element after each word.
st = [k for j in [[e, ' '] for e in s.split()] for k in j]
st.pop() # drop last.
st
>>> ['O', ' ', 'little', ' ', 'forest']
```